# When I run webload script from IDE, it runs in 45 mins. When i run same script using webload console, it takes 5 hours. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, webloadui

I have a Webload recorded script which automates some admin operations of the application. When i run the script from the webload IDE, completion of script with singles thread it is taking around 45 mins. Same script with single thread is executed from webload console, it takes almost around 5 hours. Please help with what could have been wrong? Any way i can debug what is going wrong when it is executed from the webload console?

I tried looking at the Sleep ignore settings in IDE. Sleep ignore is not configired in IDE preferences. Also I tried commenting the sleep from code. No major difference. I have a for loop to loop through the Array to perform same operation for 25 different data itmes.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would have been sleep times too. We had issues with performance when running with HTTP 2 rather than HTTP 1.1. The web application wasn't configured for HTTP 2 so every request seemed to take longer, so you could look at that.

I sometimes add a breakpoint in the code so I can step through to see if it's doing loops correctly.

It's unlikely but have you set the console to keep going for a set length of time? We usually have a goal-oriented task that continues for over an hour to test throughput even though the goal is reached after, say 10 minutes.